# Gaussian elimination - number of solutions

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

How do I know how many solutions does a system of linear equations have?

I have such system of linear equations:

$\begin{cases}
(1+b)x+y+z=1\\
x+(1+b)y+z=b\\
x+y+(1+b)z=b^2
\end{cases}$

And I would like to know if it has zero, one, or more solutions depanding on $b$ ($b\in\mathbb{R}$).

How do I do that?

Comment: Hint: Find the Row-Reduced-Echelon-Form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** write down the augumented matrix and apply Gaussian elimination to it.

**Added:** Here is what you should get

> $$ \left[ \begin {array}{cccc} 1+b&1&1&1\\0&{\frac {b
>  \left( 2+b \right) }{1+b}}&{\frac {b}{1+b}}&{\frac {b+{b}^{2}-1}{1+b}
> }\\0&0&{\frac { \left( b+3 \right) b}{2+b}}&{\frac {
> {b}^{3}+2\,{b}^{2}-b-1}{2+b}}\end {array} \right] .$$

Now, you should analyse the last row. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/547233/system-of-equation-with-3-unknown) for another approach.

Comment: that is great,+1

Comment: @datodatuashvili: Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 3):

Your matrix is $$bI_{3 \times 3} + \begin{bmatrix} 1\\ 1\\ 1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1& 1& 1\end{bmatrix}$$
The inverse of this matrix by [Sherman Morrison Woodbury](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula) formula is
$$\dfrac{I_{3 \times 3}}b - \dfrac1{b(b+3)}\begin{bmatrix} 1\\ 1\\ 1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1& 1& 1\end{bmatrix}$$
Hence, $b$ should not be equal to $0$ or $-3$ for the system to have a solution.

In the $n \times n$ case, $b$ should not be equal to $0$ or $-n$ for the system to have a solution.

Comment: very nice +1 for elegant solution

Answer (score 0):

suppose that $b=0$   then you get

$x+y+z=1$

$x+y+z=0$

$x+y+z=0$

clearly it has not solution,of course you can choose different  $b$ and test  it,or try  to reudce it to row echelon form and  determine how given system is consistent or has solution